# Error when generating OAuth token in LinkedIn Developer API (token generator)

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

Dear LinkedIn support team,

I tried to **create a OAuth 2.0 access token** with **openid OAuth flow**. While it works for profile and email OAuth flow, the process fails with an **unspecific error** when selecting openid.
In the console, I see two errors which might help you to identify the issue (see image for more details).
I would be pleased to get help as soon as possible as I need to continue the development of our application.

Thanks.

NOTE: This request is published here, as LinkedIn moved its support to stack overflow.

[Here a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlK7x.png)